# PHP Object Programming how to save data in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i am starting to use PHP object oriented ( its been a few months now ), and i was wondering when should i save the changes to my database?
Let me be more specific:
Let's say i have an object called book for which i have saved in a MYSQL database id, name and price

```
class book{
  private $id;
  private $name;
  private $price;

  /*Getters,Setters and other stuff*/
}
```

now i was wondering, if i need to edit the data in the database, changing the name of the book for example, i would obviously pass by a form, then receive the data from it, create an instance of the class book and edit the $name of this instance.
Now is it correct to edit the MYSQL data in the setter method like this?

```
class book{
  private $id;
  private $name;
  private $price;

    public setNewName($newname){ 
       $this->name = $newname;
       $query = "UPDATE ETC ETC...";
    }
}
```

What i am unsure of is if it's good practice to edit the data in the database at the same moment i edit the object or would it be better to use a query in the destruct method that updates the database? Or even another solution if there are better ones.

Comment: Relevant: google "Unit of Work"

Comment: There are numerous patterns for this and related interactions- active record, data mapper, unit of work, identity map, table/row gateway, etc. there are also numerous libraries that leal with this Doctrine, Propel, Zend_Db you should research some of these and ask more specific questions about the patterns/libraries.

Comment: read how it's done in Doctrine, or ZendFramework.

Comment: This question would be better suited to Code Review. You should consider posting it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doubts shall be cleared by reading more about [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) otherwise known as ORM.

It is widely used in many PHP frameworks and not only them.

Take a look at [doctrine2](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2) on GitHub.

Comment: I've been reading about doctrine those days but i have a question about it, since i've read i should use composer to install it, can i still install it in a shared hosting solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `Active Record`. It's a pattern where the MODEL class itself knows how to update the database. Or you can study about `DAO (Data Access Object)`, which is a pattern where you have a class that receives the object as it is and updates the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get up and running quick using [Redbean ORM](http://redbeanphp.com/) to handle all the gory details. It doesn't require any MySql setup other than the database existing with a user and password. It maps PHP classes on the fly into MySql tables/records.